# OS X 10.9, when installing ruby 2.2.2, rbenv cannot globally change default ruby 2.0.0p481 to ruby 2.2.2

Tags: ruby, macos

On my MAC OS X 10.9, I have successfully installed the Ruby 2.2.2 through rbenv.

But when I use `ruby -v` to check the version, it is still `2.0.0p481`. Even if I hit the command line `rbenv global 2.2.2`, it still shows the version to be `2.0.0`.

Could anyone help me to give some explanation?

Comment: How was rbenv installed?

Comment: what is the ruby 2.2.2 full version? do rbenv version and see what the full version is

Answer (score 3):

In my case, run below commands, has fixed my problem.

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Worked for me. I use ZSH so I just replaced it with bash.